# Sharing configurations in all sub modules in SBT

Tags: sbt

I have two test configurations that I'd like to include in all of my sub projects. I would expect there would be an easy way to do it. Currently, I'm adding them to every individual project, by calling this:

```
.configs(config1, config2)
```

For making sure some settings are included in every project, you can do this:

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.0"
```

There's also a `ThisProject` object. I wonder if I would be able to use any of these objects to add configurations to all projects.

Comment: I wonder if the fact that nobody has been able to answer this is telling.

Comment: I also wonder if the fact that only three people viewed it is telling.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `Project => Project` and pass projects in. Using sbt 0.13, you can also define a multi-project build in build.sbt.

In `project/common.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object Common {
  val Config1 = config("config1") extend(Test)
  val Config2 = config("config2") extend(Test)

  def addConfigs(proj: Project): Project = proj.configs(Config1, Config2)
}
```

In `build.sbt`:

```
import Common._

lazy val app = addConfigs(project.in(file("app")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would configurations not be applied to sub-projects if you are using a parent project with aggreagation?

```
object MyBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(id="myproject", base=file("."))
    .aggregate(sub1, sub2)
    .configs( config1, config2 )

  lazy val sub1 = Project(id = "sub1", base = file("sub1"))
  lazy val sub2 = Project(id = "sub2", base = file("sub1"))
}
```

In addition to the "ThisBuild" scope, there is also a "Global" scope that might work: [enter link description here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Scopes), but you could use a project-level plugin to apply a configuration - [global configuration with a plugin](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-tools-sbt-Question-quot-Global-quot-sbt-configuration-td3232861.html) and [SBT Plugin page](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Plugins) (see the Example plugin section).